# How to get each data from array which were saved by duplicated selectbox

Tags: html, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

#### Background

I'm creating user's profile edit page, and put selectbox for users to choose their spoken language.
And I put "+" bottun next to the selectbox for users to duplicate selectbox in case they speak several languages.

For example, when I choose Japanese, English, and Chinese, ["JA", "EN", "ZH"] is display on user's profile page. However, I cannot get each data from array. I discribed like this below.

<%= @user.language.first(3) %>（get 3 data from the front.）

Then,
["J
was displayed. It seems like computer doesn't recognize it as array data, and just 3 words including [] and "" are displayed.
I would like to know how to get each data from array.

#### views/users/edit.html.erb

```rb
  <%= form_tag("/users/#{@user.id}/update", {multipart: true}) do %>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="col-1">Spoken language:</div>
      <div class="col-2" id="input_pluralBox">
        <div id="input_plural">
          <select name="language[]" class="form-control"><%= options_for_select(languages) %>
          <input type="button" value="＋" class="add pluralBtn">
          <input type="button" value="－" class="del pluralBtn">
        </div>
      </div>       
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="save"><input id="button" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="myfunk()"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <% end %>
```

I use "language-select" gem which shows languages in the world on the part "options_for_select(languages)".

name="language[]" this part can be the problem, but I couldn't find the solution.

#### Describe to duplicate selectbox with "+" bottun

```
$(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
    $(this).parent().clone(true).insertAfter($(this).parent());
});
$(document).on("click", ".del", function() {
    var target = $(this).parent();
    if (target.parent().children().length > 1) {
        target.remove();
    }
});
```

#### models/user.rb

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :languages, inverse_of: :user
end
```

#### models/language.rb

```rb
class Language < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### Version

ruby 2.6.4p104
RubyGems 3.0.3
Rails 5.2.3

#### Postscript (views/users/edit.html.erb)

```
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
      <%= fields_for @user.language do |language| %>
      <div class="col-1"><%= f.label :language %></div>
      <div class="col-2" id="input_pluralBox">
        <div id="input_plural">
            <%= language.select(:language, options_for_select(languages)) %>
          <input type="button" value="＋" class="add pluralBtn">
          <input type="button" value="－" class="del pluralBtn">  
        </div>  
      </div><br>
      <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Save" %><br>
    <% end %>
```

If I use "form_for" and "fields_for, only the last language which user chose can be saved. (If user choose Japanese, English, and Chinese, then only Chinese is saved.

Comment: Couple of quick pointers. Replace `form_tag` with `form_for`. This will give you a form object and then on that form object you can do `form.fields_for` for `language` to build the relationship. Take a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amT27SfNhKM

Comment: Any chance to use "multiple" attribute for a select input https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select ?

Comment: Thank you, Sergii. Eventually, I would like to add one more selectbox which users can choose the level for each language (beginner, intermediate, and advanced). So, I think each language data should be hundled than selext "multiple" attribute.

Comment: Thank you, Amit. I added a postscript. But if I use "form_for" and "fields_for", only the last language which user chose can be saved. (If user choose Japanese, English, and Chinese, then only Chinese is saved. Is there something wrong in my code? :(